# Folder "node_modules" is being added by git even having a .gitignore file with a Node template

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a Node App for which I added a .gitignore file with a template for Node. But even with the .gitignore file, the node_module folder keep being committed.

After searching a lot I found two main answers. One is to use:

```
git rm -rf --cached .
git add .
```

And the other is to check if the file is encoded in ASCII or UTF-8 for example.

Well, the file is encoded in UTF-8.

If I do the git commands above, it keeps adding all the files/folders. Then, it says that my branch is up to date with the origin's one and because of that, there's nothing to commit.

Here's the code to ignore node_modules folder in the .gitignore file:

```
# Dependency directories
node_modules/
jspm_packages/
```

Comment: Did you commit .gitignore file ? If not, commit it and then the node_modules folder will be ignored.

Comment: Also, try removing forward slashes from .gitinore file.

Just keep 
# Dependency directories
node_modules
jspm_packages

Comment: The .gitignore file is already committed and removing forward slashes had no effect too.

Comment: Given the computer-output quoted text in the question, I can't see any evidence that unwanted files are actually committed. What specifically leads you to believe that they are in *commits* and not merely in your *work-tree* as usual?